# Creating feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with the MNIST dataset and I am creating the following dictionary:

```
feed_dict={x: train_inputs, y: range(0, 10)}
```

Here, `y` is the label applied to the examples and it takes values between `0` and `9`.

However, I am getting this error:

```
% (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'
```

Any idea about what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign values to `x` and `y`? Are they assigned as part of a `for` loop prior to this code, or are you trying to use a dict comprehension?

Comment: did you try *y = np.array([range(0,10)])* ??

Comment: The placeholder y expects the shape to be : [batch_size, 10]. So input np.expand_dims(x, axis=0) for a single input.